# How to import geoJSON point file to ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: geojson, import, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to ArcGIS Javascript and so far I was using ArcGIS online service to import point feature layers. But now I need to use geoJSON files to import point feature layers. How can I do that? I checked the samples in the ESRI website and could not find anything.


I am using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript v4.3.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the geoJson to [Graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html) and add them to the map pretty easily (you can probably even cast to `FeatureLayer`).  Esri has created a nice library to convert between geojson and esri json format, it's called [geojson-utils](https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils). I have used it in the past and it works pretty nicely.

The following code worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>GeoJson test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style>
    body,
    html,
    #main {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
  <script src="./test.js"></script> //my geojson test data is in here
  <!-- <script src="./jsonConverters.js"></script> -->
  <script>
    var map; //

    require([
      "esri/map",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
      "esri/graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/Color",
      "./jsonConverters.js", //this is the esri geojson-utils module
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Color, jsonConverters
    ) {
      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "streets",
        center: [-93.447, 44.781],
        zoom: 10
      });
      // symbol for graphics
      var pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
        "diamond",
        20,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(
          "solid",
          new Color([88, 116, 152]), 2
        ),
        new Color([88, 116, 152, 0.45])
      );
      var esriJson = jsonConverters.geoJsonConverter().toEsri(geojson); //geojson is my geojson data
      var gl = new GraphicsLayer()
      esriJson.features.forEach(function(ft) {
        var graphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: ft.geometry,
          symbol: pointSymbol.toJson(),
          attributes: ft.attributes,
          infoTemplate: {
            title: '${Photo_Name}',
            content: '<a href=${Hyperlink} target="_blank">View Photo</a>'
          }
        })
        gl.add(graphic);
      });
      map.addLayer(gl);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;">
    <div id="map" dojotype="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

As pointed out below by @BjornSvensson, looks like the `goejson-utils` project is not actively maintained, instead have a look at [Terraformer](https://github.com/Esri/Terraformer) or [arcgis-to-geojson](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils).

Comment: This seems to be for ArcGIS Javascript version 3.20. Do you know if it works with the latest 4.3??

Comment: Yes, that is using the 3.20 API.  However, I imagine the code for 4.3 would be very similar. I haven't done much testing with the 4.x API yet. The `geojson-utils` just converts the features to esri json format, from there it is very easy to integrate with JS API.

Comment: Note that the readme for that project says it's deprecated and recommends two additional options. https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils